# QuTiP: Resolving inconsistent Qobj shapes

Tags: python, qutip

This was previously explored in [QuTiP TypeError: Incompatible Qobj shapes with tensor product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51179989/qutip-typeerror-incompatible-qobj-shapes-with-tensor-product/51191385#comment93420626_51191385) but I'm not sure about the answer there.

Suppose I define `A = tensor(qeye(2), qeye(2))` and `B = qeye(4)`, I cannot multiply them because the object shapes are inconsistent.

However, the matrices are of the same dimension and I would like to "flatten" `A` to allow it to be multiplied by `B`. If I have a combination of seperable operators and non-seperable ones, how do I use them together? In other words, `B` cannot be simplified further so what should I do to `A` to allow them to be multiplied?

EDIT: The clunky looking Qobj(A.data.toarray()) works but I'll leave this open in case someone has a better idea or understands why QuTiP does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes using `Qobj.data` you get the matrix representing the state or operator.

Hence `A.data * B.data` allows you to multiply them together. Once you've done that you can enclose it in `Qobj(A.data * B.data)` to make it a quantum object.